# Lookback API: Test Case Results?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

Is there a way through the Lookback API to see Test Case Results related to Test Cases? - With the WSAPI a TestCase has a Results field that is a collection of TestCaseResults, however when I query the Lookback API for TestCase (with fields=true) I don't see any Results that are associated with the TestCase.

What I am trying to get to are metrics around test cases, and their results over time (how long between a test case failing and a test case passing, how often test cases pass on their first run, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage of the open preview for the LBAPI service, Test Case Results aren't aggregated into the Lookback database for reasons of scalability. This is partially due to the detailed "snapshot" nature of Lookback intersecting with the typically very large volume of Test Case Results that are logged into Rally on a daily basis.

There's certainly the possibility that Test Case Results could be added to Lookback. From a user perspective, is there a tradeoff that could be made for how far back in time Lookback might go with TCR's, in order to include detailed snapshots? 90 Days? 120 Days? This feedback could be really helpful to inform the scaling decisions around this aspect of the API.

Comment: For me, since the teams I work with are either on 1 week Sprints or 2 weeks Sprints, 30-60 days back (enough for 4 Sprints worth of data) would probably be plenty.